# Js массив в PHP массив

Tags: php, html, xpath

У меня следующая задача, есть страница откуда нужно спарсить информацию, проблема состоит в том что информация которую мне нужно добыть, она записана в виде JS массива (в моём случае это получается строка), типа

```
var restaurants = [
  ['5QN7N', [2, 3, 5], [21, 91, 231], 1, 'Amigo Pizzaservice','', 0,7,15,12.04,12,0,0,0,1,1,51.0273348,13.7611161,2,45,............
```

Массив довольно большой, это часть в качестве примера.

Можно ли как-то преобразовать такую строку в PHP массив или json для работы с отдельными элементами?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод stringify:

> Метод JSON.stringify(value, replacer, space) преобразует («сериализует») значение в JSON-строку.

```
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var j = JSON.stringify(numbers);
```

Comment: мне на PHP это сделать нужно, а вы насколько понимаю JS написали

Comment: Тогда смотрите функции php [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)